# Date from string boost::gregorian

Tags: c++, date, boost-date-time

Hi I have two strings:

```
entertime "2014-03-06T09:35:36Z" 
exittime "2014-03-06T09:38:36Z"
```

I want to be able to return the difference, which in this case should return 3min.

My method looks like this:

```
 boost::gregorian::date returnTime(std::string entertime, std::string exittime){
 boost::gregorian::date denter = boost::gregorian::from_string(entertime);
 boost::gregorian::date dexit = boost::gregorian::from_string(entertime);
 boost::gregorian::date dresult = dexit-denter;
```

Is there any way to get this time difference?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no direct converter for your particular timestamp, if you could remove all the delimiters and form a string which meets the iso spec, then you can do the below:

```
  auto ts1 = boost::posix_time::from_iso_string("20140306T093536Z");
  auto ts2 = boost::posix_time::from_iso_string("20140306T093836Z");

  std::cout << (ts2 - ts1) << std::endl;
```

This should output `00:03:00` as you expect. NOTE The types here are (`ts1` & `ts2` are `boost::posix_time::ptime` and the delta is a `boost::posix_time::time_duration`)